# error C4839: non-standard use of class 'ATL::CW2AEX<520>' as an argument to a variadic function

Tags: c++, atl

I'm using Curl in a project and my function is returning a error about CW2AEX..

```
    const TCHAR* path; 
    const TCHAR* fileName;

    TCHAR url[ MAX_PATH ] = { 0 };
    _stprintf( url, _T( "%s%s" ), path, fileName );

    char errorCode[ CURL_ERROR_SIZE ] = { 0 };
    function( curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER,        errorCode );    
    function( curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,             0 );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,     1 );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,         0 );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,          isMemoryDownload ? ( void* )( &memoryFile ) : ( void* )( &diskFile ) );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,      isMemoryDownload ? CNetwork::WriteToMemory : CNetwork::WriteToDisk );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA,       0 );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,   CNetwork::Pursuit );
    function( curl, CURLOPT_URL,                CW2AEX< sizeof( url ) >( url ) );
```

My guess is that it should load the value explicitly in order to compile it.
Not quiet sure?

Answer (score 10):

The error message gives you a hint: for a variadic function argument you have to resolve the type ambiguity and cast the helper class to acceptable type:

```
function(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (LPCSTR) CW2AEX< sizeof( url ) >( url ) );
```

You can also make it simpler at minimal cost (using [`CStringA`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/840af012-a402-4659-87ce-2bb029d2f300/cstring-to-cstringa-in-unicode-character-set?forum=vcgeneral)):

```
function(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (LPCSTR) CStringA(url));
```